# Getting the length of a line formed by dragging

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I want to calculate the length of drag. ie the length of the line created by dragging the cursor from one point to another on html canvas. How to achieve it in kineticjs??
ie on dragstart to dragend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know kinetic, but using jquery would look something like this:

```
var telemetry = {
    $target: null,
    startPosition: {x:0,y:0},
    distance: 0,
    getMousePosition: function(event){
        var position = {
            x: event.pageX - this.$target.offset().left,
            y: event.pageY - this.$target.offset().top
        }
        return position;
    },
    getDistance: function(startPosition, endPosition){
        //find distance in each x and y directions
        var dx = endPosition.x - startPosition.x;
        var dy = endPosition.y - startPosition.y;

        // use pythagorean theorem
        return Math.sqrt((dx*dx) + (dy*dy));
    },
    onMouseDown: function(event){
        this.startPosition = this.getMousePosition(event);
    },
    onMouseUp: function(event){
        this.distance = this.getDistance(this.startPosition, this.getMousePosition(event));
    }
}

telemetry.$target = $('#myCanvas');

telemetry.$target.mousedown(function(event){
    telemetry.onMouseDown(event);
}).mouseup(function(event){
    telemetry.onMouseUp(event);
    alert('you dragged ' + telemetry.distance + 'px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/HUdUH/

Answer (score 0):

well, in kineticjs you would do something like:

```
var point1;
var point2;
layer.on('dragstart', function(){
     point1 = stage.getUserPosition();
});
layer.on('dragend', function(){
     point2 = stage.getUserPosition();
     var xDist = point2.x - point1.x;
     var yDist = point2.y - point1.y;
     alert( Math.sqrt((xDist*xDist) + (yDist*yDist)) ); // this pops up a message of the length of the line, you could just do a return or assign a value to something
     //distance = Math.sqrt((xDist*xDist) + (yDist*yDist)); //alternative
})
```